# Master data services deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services

What is the best approach to keep Production,dev and test enviroments in sync?

We have Master Data Services database in our development, Test and Production environments. Data is been entered into Production and we need to keep our test and development servers in Sync. I couldn't find the documentation to handle this.

I am not sure if this process is correct-

For moving updated data from Development we are following this process-

create second version of the model and make the changes in it and then deploy the 2nd version to test and prod.

Can we do this same above process from Production to test and Development to keep them  in Sync?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

---

- [Snapshot replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx)

> Snapshot replication distributes data exactly as it appears at a specific moment in time and does not monitor for updates to the data. When synchronization occurs, the entire snapshot is generated and sent to Subscribers.

---

- [Log shipping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx)

> SQL Server Log shipping allows you to automatically send transaction log backups from a primary database on a primary server instance to one or more secondary databases on separate secondary server instances. The transaction log backups are applied to each of the secondary databases individually.

Comment: Thank you.MDS has its own Deployment options, I am confused if we can use the same process to move data between environments

Comment: @Vibha To be honest I have never worked with MDS. I just looked at [what MDS is about](http://www.slideshare.net/jamserra/introduction-to-microsofts-master-data-services-mds) and I see no mention of the functionality you seek in MDS. I could be wrong though, as I said I've never worked with it. It looks more like a data consolidation/data consistency/business centric utility. The options I listed are available in SQL Server Standard/BI/Enterprise edition. If you have any of those version and use SQL Server for your database, the options I listed are the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

MDS has tool which is called MDSModelDeploy. You can create package with all business rules, schema and data. Ship it over to some other machine and.

- clone model (preserving keys, etc)
- update model

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486956.aspx)